# Add Button by id for SwiftUI inside ForEach using shorthand argument name $0

Tags: swift, button, foreach, swiftui

How to add `Button` inside the `ForEach` ? Works with `Text` but no luck with `Button`. Will like to make use of shorthand argument name `$0`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    let emojiMoves = ["", "", "✂️"]

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(emojiMoves, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this could work but I like the simplicity of `$0`

```
ForEach(0 ..< self.emojiMoves.count, id: \.self ) { number in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.emojiMoves[(number)]
                    })   
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
ForEach(self.emojiMoves, id: \.self ) {
   Button($0){

   }
}
```

Comment: worded like a charm, tried this approach before but forgot to add .self , thanks!